# How to resolve the drop down length issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had created a filtering dropdowns on hover, where by selecting the country name  on hover from the first dropdown the respective destinations will be appear in the second dropdown on hover.  Here the problem is when we hover on the destinations dropdown the length of the dropdown is showing higher than the list items,

```js
function DropList() {
 var n = document.getElementById("iFunction").options.length;
 document.getElementById("iFunction").size = n;
}

function handleSelect(elm){
 window.location = elm.value;
}

function DropNew() {
 var n = document.getElementById("iOperation").options.length;
 document.getElementById("iOperation").size = n;
}
        
function handleSelect(elm){
 window.location = elm.value;
}

function changeddl(obj) {
 var text = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
 var ddl2 = document.querySelectorAll('#iOperation option');
 
 for (var i = 1; i < ddl2.length; i++) {
  var option = ddl2[i];
  
  option.style.display = 'none';
  
  if (text == 'Pick a Country') {
   if (['Pick a Destination'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'none'
  }

  if (text == 'India') {
   if (['Bangalore', 'Delhi','Gujarat', 'Kerala', 'Kutch Desert','South Kerala', 'Tamil Nadu Forests','Mysore'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'block'
  }

  if (text == 'Sri Lanka') {
   if (['Sri Lanka'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'block'
  }

  if (text == 'Sweden') {
   if (['Sweden'].indexOf(option.text) > -1)
    option.style.display = 'block'
  }
 }
}
```

```css
option:hover {
 background: #428ffa;
 color: white;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:10px; float:left">
 <select id="iFunction" name="nFunction" onmouseover="DropList()" onmouseout="this.size=1;" onchange="changeddl(this)">
  <option value="" selected="">Pick a Country</option>
  <option value="">India</option>
  <option value="">Sri Lanka</option>
  <option value="">Sweden</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div style="height: 10px; float: left; margin-left: 50px">
 <select id="iOperation" onchange="location = this.value;" onmouseover="DropNew()" onmouseout="this.size=1;" name="nOperation">
  <option value="" selected="">Pick a Destination</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Bangalore</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.flipkart.com/">Delhi</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Gujarat</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Kerala</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Kutch Desert</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.flipkart.com/">South Kerala</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.snapdeal.com/">Tamil Nadu Forests</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Sri Lanka</option>
  <option class="hidden" value="https://www.paytm.com/">Sweden</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Here the problem is when we hover on the destinations dropdown the length of the dropdown is showing higher than the list items, i want the destination dropdown list to be restricted to the item length only, kindly help me how can i do this

Comment: You can not hide `<option>` in some browsers. Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Comment: You are missing `else` conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change DropNew function to

```js
var countryArrays = [ ['Bangalore', 'Delhi','Gujarat', 'Kerala', 'Kutch Desert','South Kerala', 'Tamil Nadu Forests','Mysore'],
['Sweden'],['Sri Lanka'] ];

function DropNew() {
  
var index = document.getElementById("iFunction").selectedIndex - 1;

if (index >= 0){
    document.getElementById("iOperation").size = countryArrays[index].length + 1;
  }

}
```

and add "Mysore" option into "iOperation"

```html
<option class="hidden" value="https://www.amazon.in/">Mysore</option>
```